# SessionNotCreatedException Selenium while trying to load a chrome session/profile

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

I want to automate a page login using Selenium. The thing is that on the login page, there is a Google recaptcha. So, what I would like to do to bypass that reCAPTCHA is load my profile cookies and session to bypass the login. However, the problem is that when I run my code, it opens a Chrome tab with my session opened, but then it fails on the line: `driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)`

The program throws the error:

> Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
> (session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
> (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)

And doesn't continue the automation.

My code is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=/home/username/.config/google-chrome")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
options.add_argument("--disable-browser-side-navigation")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

The problem i'm sure is the line: `options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=/home/username/.config/google-chrome")` because without it it works fine, i've tried manually uploading the chrome default profile path:

```
chrome_path = C:\\Users\\myUser\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default
options.add_argument(f'--user-data-dir={chrome_path}')
```

But it doesn't load things like my search history and Gmail profile picture so i don't think that it loads my actual profile correctly. So what i need is a method to make my profile load without giving me that error or another way to load my chrome data.